# javascript joystick for a camera

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, svg

Hey I need to create a joystick for a camera control.
The joystick need to be able to move to four directions: left,right,up and down and two have functionality of stop.
I have search the web for hours, finally I found something which called nipplejs.
I have attached the code of nipplejs to this thread:

```js
var radius = 100;

var sampleJoystick = {
    mode: 'static',
    position: {
      left: '50%',
      top: '50%'
    },
    size: radius*2,
    color: 'black'
};

var joystick;
var position;
joystick = nipplejs.create(sampleJoystick);
joystick.on('start end', function(evt, data) {
  position = data;
}).on('move', function(evt, data) {
  position = data;
}).on('dir:up plain:up dir:left plain:left dir:down' +
      'plain:down dir:right plain:right',
      function(evt, data) {
  //position=data;
}
     ).on('pressure', function(evt, data) {
  position=data;
});
```

```html
<script src="//yoannmoinet.github.io/nipplejs/javascripts/nipplejs.js"></script>
<div id="zone_joystick">
</div>
```

At first glance it looks like the perfect library, but on second look I can see that I have no directions indicators on the joystick and I can't implement a stop behavior with this joystick, and it won't be intuitive control for elders who will use the software.

I am looking for alternative solution for a panel control which have the functionalities which I have talked about.

functionalities:
joystick which can be turn to 4 different directions: Left,Right,Up and Down.
joystick have a stop functionality as well.

Comment: SO is not the place to ask for libraries or resources. If your question were about how to add that functionality to your joystick it would fit better here

Comment: I am not asking for library, I am asking if somebody who could help me in modify nipplejs or found a better solution to my problem.
I have looked for hours and didn't find any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to the hardware first, before you can read its input. Have you considered using the browser native GamePad API? This doesn't work in all browsers though.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API

Comment: no I don't need this, I connect to the camera via C# process, I send a requests from the ui to a C# code which perform the actual moving.
I am talking about the UI, I need to build the UI for this camera.

Comment: OK, but why can't you overlay an SVG with a clear UI on top of the nipplejs functionality? Nipplejs seems to work very well.

Comment: I am new to svg, I could try this but I don't know where to start.
No chance for any push or help in doing so?

Comment: You could use a div with position absolute. Place that div on top of the nipplejs interface. Inside that div you can put any kind of image (svg or png) that clarifies the meaning of the joystick. Finally, you could use CSS to make the div unselectable.